# getValue undefined in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, undefined

New to sencha touch here. I've checked out quite a few tutorials online. I am having an issue trying to get the value of a text field. The error I am getting when I click my login button is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getValue' of undefined`. Does that mean my `Ext.getCmp` is undefined then? I have this panel wrapped in the regular `Ext.setup....onReady:.....`

```
var login = new Ext.Panel({
    height:'auto',
    scroll:'vertical',
    layout:{
        type:'vbox',
        align:'center'
    },
    items:[
        {
            cls:'launchscreen',
            html:logo,
            padding:10
        },
        new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            width:300,
            cls:'loginform',
            items:[
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    title: 'Login',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name : 'username',
                            label: 'Username',
                            labelWidth: 85
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'passwordfield',
                            name : 'password',
                            label: 'Password',
                            labelWidth: 85
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Submit',
                    ui: 'confirm',
                    handler:function()
                    {
                        alert(Ext.getCmp('username').getValue());
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
    ]
});
```

EDIT: I was able to get the value if I set the `id` property on the text field. I've seen some example where the `id` isn't set and they get the value based off the `name` property. So I guess my question now is am I supposed to get the value based off `id` or `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Ext.getCmp()` you have to provide the **ID** of the element whose value you want. See Sencha API doc's for this:

***getCmp( String id )**
This is shorthand reference to Ext.ComponentManager.get. Looks up an existing Component by id
Parameters
id : String
The component id*

You can also find the element by name, but I think it is faster by ID but perhaps also a bit expensive for the browser's engine. Can't say anything about that really.

Anyway, finding field by name is possible by using `findField()` method. With this method you should provide the **id or name** of the field that you want. See API doc: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-findField

Example:

```
var fieldValue= Ext.getCmp("YourFormID").getForm().findField("FieldName").getValue();
```

Comment: yep, I think passing the ID is better in the end. Thanks for the info. I wasn't able to find the getCmp method in their docs